# BLU Advance 5.0 HD: Unknown apps source: androidrbx, mfn, swak news

Tags: applications, malware

On my year-old BLU Advance 5.0 HD phone (running Android 6.0), I recently had a few suspicious incidents where the Audio Profile seemed to have changed from Meeting to Normal on its own, and once where the phone started playing music by itself (and not anything that's on the phone). At this point, I noticed three strange entries in the apps list: "androidrbx", "mfn" and "swak news" (all lowercase), all with generic icons. I have never installed anything of the sort, and the swak news one had all kinds of app permissions, which I had not granted. I deleted all three, but they were back the next day. Repeated this for a few days then figured I had malware and did a factory restore.

On the fresh install, the only additional (Play store) apps I added were Safari Queue and Duolingo, which I hoped were fairly trustworthy. No reappearance of the above trio until today, after an update of 6 apps — 5 being Google system apps (Calculator, Keep, Android Messages, Gboard and YouTube), and the last being Duolingo. Now they are back. I foolishly did all the updates at once, so I can't pinpoint the culprit (although Duolingo obviously seems most likely, unless one of the Google apps somehow got corrupted).

So now I'm trying to gather some intel from those who have more experience with the platform before I continue on the tedious process of trying to isolate the offending app or update. (If there are better forums, please point me there.) My main question is whether this is known malware, or at least has the hallmarks of such? I have searched and found no references to any of these names (except for a seemingly legit but different Swak News app), which surprised me, but perhaps the names are randomly generated. If these are legitimate "helper" apps or something, I would like to know to which app they belong, but they seem awfully suspicious to be such.

Comment: Not a virus (no such thing on Android), but definitely smells for some malware – which even might have managed to convert itself into a system app, so only flashing a clean ROM would safely get rid of it. Might also play "sleeper" after the reset waiting for updates or some other events, to make it harder to spot. You could try fresh again, and not accept any updates for a week (plus after that, only applying them one-by-one starting with the "most trustworthy"). I'd suspect none of the named candidates, Duolingo included.

Comment: You're right, @Izzy, I used the wrong term. Was going to edit my post, but you beat me to it! Done now. Your assessment is what I suspected, but I've already done a factory restore and limited installs and updates, though I got careless with the last batch, since they were all Google system apps, save for one. But I'll start over if there's no other likely explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Though you still missed one "virus" :) And as I wrote: if it's really a malware that managed to convert itself into a system app, factory reset won't get rid of that. You'd really need to flash a clean ROM then. I still very much doubt one of those apps is the culprit: we'd heard many more people crying then. Not only for the GApps involved; Duolingo is a well established software, too. Though I've not heard it came pre-installed on any device; so make sure to check you didn't catch a fake/clone with that one.

Comment: Thanks, @Izzy! I did mention that Duolingo was one of two apps I added, beyond the pre-installed set. I agree, I would have expected much more noise about an infection in an app like that, so maybe it's not likely. It's curious that I did not see the mystery apps return (and I was checking regularly) until after today's update, when they had been reinstalling every day prior to wiping the system. I will have to look into the clean-ROM option. No idea what that entails. But thanks for the tips!

Comment: As I wrote above, that might be an "initial sleeper-mode" so you don't suspect the source. Not sure, though – just a possibility.

Comment: I also have a BLU (Advance 5.0 HD), which showed similar behavior a couple of weeks ago: it played random sounds, kept turning the wifi off, and once displayed a popup on the home screen (unfortunately I didn't read it before closing it). The app list also showed "Androidrbx", "mfn", and "swak news". After a factory reset, all seemed fine for a couple of days, and now the behavior and apps are back. The Avast app on the phone shows nothing, and there is no suspicious activity on the associated Google account. I don't have Duolingo installed. Seems like this may be an issue related to BLU then?

Comment: At least two more people with BLU phones have the same issue, see https://www.amazon.ca/gp/customer-reviews/R1TSX0FHVEK6SK/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B01E9BNCQ4. I've contacted BLU about this.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the Amazon thread, @flo_ca! That helps narrow it down. If I have time, I will install updates one by one to see which one has the code in question. I will contact BLU as well (the more they hear about it, the better), but please post back here if you learn anything more!

Comment: I've contacted BLU and they are clueless, don't know about the issue and won't take responsibility for it

Comment: Update: "mfn" and "swak news" have come back 3 days after a factory restore, even though I've turned off all updates and have nothing but the factory apps. ("androidrbx" has not returned yet, though.) So looks like @Izzy was right about the sleeper mode. So now the question is whether they are part of the restore image or somehow attached to the boot loader (or whatever it is that remains to do the factory reset).

Comment: Did you get any OTA (aka "official update") from your provider/manufacturer shortly before the issue started? Then they might have messed up. If not, you must somehow have caught it (installed something shortly before the issue started?), and it managed making itself into system. Finding the culprit is a tedious job. Easiest approach would be flashing a clean image.

Comment: @Izzy: There was an OTA update, but my recollection was that it was a month or two earlier. I hadn't installed anything recently when I first noticed the problem, but the malware activation could have been delayed. I will look into the clean-image route; not something I'm familiar with, and I don't know how to find a trustworthy source for the ROM. (There's nothing on the BLU site.)

Comment: For the latter, may I point you to [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](/q/17152/16575)